# What bitwise ~ operator do to a number

Tags: coffeescript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I found this in the little book on coffeescript

```
!!~ string.indexOf "test"
```

and I test

```
~-1 == 0
~0  == -1
~3 == -4
~-2 == 1
```

So what exactly happening here and why `~` return `0` on `-1`, does `-1` is the only value that produce `0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [two's complement integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), -1 is a sequence of all 1-bits. The [`~` bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Bitwise_operators):

> Inverts the bits of its operand.

Inverting the bits in a sequence of 1-bits gives you a sequence of 0-bits and a sequence of 0-bits is the integer 0. So `~i` is zero if and only if `i === -1`.

[`String#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

> [...] returns -1 if the value is not found

Putting those two things together tells us that this:

```
~ string.indexOf "test"
```

is zero if and only if `"test"` is not present in `string`. Then we add the `!!` "cast to boolean" trick and the fact that `0` is the only integer that is falsey in JavaScript and we have:

```
!!~ string.indexOf "test"
```

being `true` if `"test"` appears in `string` and `false` otherwise; or, in sensible and readable code, that's the same as:

```
string.indexOf("test") != -1
```

If the book is actually suggesting that you write code like that then you should burn that book and find a better one. Using all that bit twiddling is just the sort of "cleverness" that will make everyone maintaining your code hate you.

Comment: If first show `... isnt -1` and then say "Or even better, hijack the bitwise operator so we don't have to do a -1 comparison"

Comment: I fail to see how an opaque mess of symbols qualifies as *better* (especially when it involves three times as many operators!), perhaps the author is over-enamored with their own cleverness.